# A table with generated virtual column from Json, get error(3102) when insert data using procedure

Tags: mysql, json

A table with generated virtual column from Json, get error(3102) when insert data using procedure. however, I using sql DML

```
INSERT INTO player_js(player_js.content)VALUES('{"nam":"hehe","lv":1,"car":2,"mny":7}')
```

to insert data is ok. tell me why~???

the sql:

```
-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------
USE GameDB;
DROP TABLE if EXISTS player_js;
-- create table
CREATE TABLE `player_js` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`content` json DEFAULT NULL,
`name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin GENERATED ALWAYS AS (json_extract(content,'$.nam')) VIRTUAL,
`level` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (json_extract(content,'$.lv')) VIRTUAL,
`career` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (json_extract(content,'$.car')) VIRTUAL,
`money` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (json_extract(content,'$.mny')) VIRTUAL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `idx_level` (`level`),
KEY `idx_money` (`money`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5005 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS SavePlayer_js;
delimiter $$
-- create procedure
CREATE PROCEDURE `SavePlayer_js`(IN content JSON)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO player_js(player_js.content)VALUES(content);
END$$
delimiter;

CALL SavePlayer_js('{"nam":"hehe","lv":1,"car":2,"mny":7}'); -- get error(3102):Expression of generated column 'name' contains a disallowed function
```

Comment: works fine here. Did you share the exact code?

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of the parameter in the stored procedure. See [Name Conflicts within Stored Routines](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-restrictions.html) in documentation.

```sql
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `player_js`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE `player_js` (
    ->   `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   `content` JSON DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `name` VARCHAR(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin GENERATED ALWAYS AS (JSON_EXTRACT(`content`,'$.nam')) VIRTUAL,
    ->   `level` INT(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (JSON_EXTRACT(`content`,'$.lv')) VIRTUAL,
    ->   `career` INT(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (JSON_EXTRACT(`content`,'$.car')) VIRTUAL,
    ->   `money` INT(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (JSON_EXTRACT(`content`,'$.mny')) VIRTUAL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    ->   KEY `idx_level` (`level`),
    ->   KEY `idx_money` (`money`)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `SavePlayer_js`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER $$

mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE `SavePlayer_js`(IN `content` JSON)
    -> BEGIN
    ->   INSERT INTO `player_js`
    ->     (`player_js`.`content`)
    ->   VALUES
    ->     (`content`);
    -> END$$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;

mysql> CALL `SavePlayer_js`('{"nam":"hehe","lv":1,"car":2,"mny":7}');
ERROR 3102 (HY000): Expression of generated column 'name' contains a disallowed function.

mysql> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `SavePlayer_js`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER $$

mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE `SavePlayer_js`(IN `p_content` JSON)
    -> BEGIN
    ->   INSERT INTO `player_js`
    ->     (`player_js`.`content`)
    ->   VALUES
    ->     (`p_content`);
    -> END$$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;

mysql> CALL `SavePlayer_js`('{"nam":"hehe","lv":1,"car":2,"mny":7}');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `id`,
    ->   `content`,
    ->   `name`,
    ->   `level`,
    ->   `career`,
    ->   `money`
    -> FROM
    ->   `player_js`\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
     id: 1
content: {"lv": 1, "car": 2, "mny": 7, "nam": "hehe"}
   name: "hehe"
  level: 1
 career: 2
  money: 7
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**UPDATE**

This looks like a bug. If you access the table before executing the stored procedure, it works as expected.

```sql
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `player_js`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE `player_js` (
    ->   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   `content` JSON DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `name` VARCHAR(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin GENERATED ALWAYS AS (JSON_EXTRACT(`content`,'$.nam')) VIRTUAL,
    ->   `level` INT(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (JSON_EXTRACT(`content`,'$.lv')) VIRTUAL,
    ->   `career` INT(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (JSON_EXTRACT(`content`,'$.car')) VIRTUAL,
    ->   `money` INT(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (JSON_EXTRACT(`content`,'$.mny')) VIRTUAL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    ->   KEY `idx_level` (`level`),
    ->   KEY `idx_money` (`money`)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `SavePlayer_js`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER $$

mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE `SavePlayer_js`(IN `content` JSON)
    -> BEGIN
    ->   INSERT INTO `player_js`
    ->     (`player_js`.`content`)
    ->   VALUES
    ->     (`content`);
    -> END$$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `id`,
    ->   `content`,
    ->   `name`,
    ->   `level`,
    ->   `career`,
    ->   `money`
    -> FROM
    ->   `player_js`\G
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> CALL `SavePlayer_js`('{"nam":"hehe","lv":1,"car":2,"mny":7}');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `id`,
    ->   `content`,
    ->   `name`,
    ->   `level`,
    ->   `career`,
    ->   `money`
    -> FROM
    ->   `player_js`\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
     id: 1
content: {"lv": 1, "car": 2, "mny": 7, "nam": "hehe"}
   name: "hehe"
  level: 1
 career: 2
  money: 7
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```